# admob ads problem in uity

Tags: unity, advertisements, admob

In unity 2019.1.3f I want to implement google admob ads in that game but after importing GoogleMobileAds-v3.18.0.unitypackage in to my project I got a porblem.

when I hit play button

[image: Image 1]
this window poped up.

Please help me regarding the problem

Thank you

Comment: What happens after it finishes resolving Android dependencies?

Comment: game runs perfectly in editor but in real device ads not showing. after some debugging I found that the problem is in MobileAds.Initialize(appID); after running this line of code next line does not execute. I can't understand what is the problem.